# SharePoint online Use-Cases

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library

We basically use SharePoint online to store our files and documents.
Besides that we have some sites for different teams that have a task calendar (task that have a time schedule).

I wanted to ask what would be some other good use-cases that we as a team can use SharePoint for?

What should we implement additionally on our SharePoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We as team can use SharePoint as collaboration platform. Below use cases can be implemented for team.

- Social collaboration features like community site for forum like experience
- Create a knowledge base for known issues, learning etc..
- Use News feed
- Use task list for tracking project activities, assignments, due dates.
- Tag document with metadata for categorizing content.

As you are SharePoint online, I would suggest you to use MS Teams which sole purpose is for team collaboration, document sharing, content creation, shared mail box, chat.

Comment: We use it as a team collaboration. Metadata for content categories and we use tracking activities. I was just wondering is there is something specific that we could implement. thank you

Comment: pretty much it.... you can totally customize it and do gamification like stack overflow.. idea generation platform...

Comment: So I guess we have been doing the rights tthings. I just got the tasks to look for different things we can implement on our sharepoint.

Comment: yes...please vote and mark as answer if it was helpful....